# Difference between maps/dir and maps/embed

Tags: google-maps

I saw the following Google Maps code in a website:

```
          href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir//Borsigstra%C3%9Fe+4,+30115+Hamburg,+Niemcy/@82.528634,43.3909246,17z/data=!4m13!1m4!3m3!1s0x47a851eed437e2b7:0x31501b0af0ac91b4!2sBornigstra%C3%9Fe+4!3b1!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x47a851eed437e2b7:0x31501b0af0ac91b4!2m2!1d13.3909246!2d52.528634"
```

I wanted to replace this with my own location. 
When I go to Google Maps, search my address and get the sharable html code, I get

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2533.5747769945215!2d8.672258415914873!3d50.579269285955185!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47bc58ec0d5dbe19%3A0x3e2e9cd7b8a6d28a!2sBleichstra%C3%9Fe+34%2C+35390+Gie%C3%9Fen!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sde!4v1529588183346" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

What is the difference between these 2 formats, and how could I get my own address in the format of the first format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter can only be used as an embedded element i.e. appearing in the page like an image.

The former is a shortcut to the directions 'mode' in google maps

Is this the link you wanted? https://www.google.com/maps/dir//50.5792659,8.6744471/@50.579266,8.674447,16z?hl=en-GB

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's the link. In contrast to the first format in my post, the link you posted doesn't have the street and city name included. Is that not necessary? Or what is it used for?

Comment: The street and city name don't need to be included in the link url, if that's what you're asking. Google maps can just link directly to the Lat/Long of a location.
Did you want the link to appear in a specific format?

Comment: No, I didn't want any specific format. Your solution works perfectly fine. Thank you.

Comment: How did you get that link, please?

Comment: Honestly, I put the <iframe> code you posted into jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o3zaw8sd/ then clicked the "Directions" button on the map, which opened it in a new window with the desired url.